# Google Analytics BatchGet Report | Report Names

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api

What would be the best solution to give a report a name when make a `report:batchGet`?

```
var url = Google.Common.Configuration.Endpoints.ReportBatchGet;
var reportRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_reportRequests);

try
{
    var tReports = await gc.PostAsyncTask(url,reportRequest);

    int cnt = 0;
    foreach (var report in tReports.reports)
    {
        if (report != null)
        {
            DataTable dt =  Google.Utils.ReportHandler.GoolgeBatchReportCreateDataTable(report,
                            _reportRequests.reportRequests.FirstOrDefault().viewId, **"REPORT_NAME"**);
                            Utils.ReportHandler.DataSetCellHandler(dt);

        }
    }
```

I have an array of reports which I convert into Json and make a post to get the data, the results are fine. 
I would like to give a name to the DataTable when convert the results in a `DataTable` but Google Analytics do not accept a report name or alias in the `batchGet`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of adding a report name to each report within in a batch request. to the Google Analytics Reporting API.

It is already an issue I have spotted and I have requested they add it to the API.  The team accepted my request but there is no time frame on when they will add this feature.

Comment: @DalmTo do you think this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/batching#details, can solve my problems regarding batch requests? I'm just having troubles to know how to perform this kind of request in C#. I don't want to use their sdk.

Comment: I haven't used the Batching from v3 actually.   Any special reason why you don't want to use the Google .Net client library?   there is also a feature request for returning V4 data as a datatable like v3 does.   No idea if they will add that it didn't sound like it last time I spoke with them.

Comment: No special reason, I'm in a middle of the project and I didn't want to waste time to understand the how the sdk works, because I've already created my wrappers and my methods to export the data to DataTables etc.

Comment: There is sample code on the site https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples there is more here Sample project should help https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4 (Disclaimer both were created by me)  The official client library makes things a lot easer for you.    I have an application which I couldn't use the client library for took me several weeks to do what I could have had up and running in 5 minutes using the library.